# Flash Media Server, how to use allowedHTMLdomains.txt on 2nd app

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-media-server

I am configuring our Adobe Flash Media Server 3.5 and need some help.

I have carefully followed the documentation on how to duplicate the vod service:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_Deving/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773cfae-7ff3.html

I successfully created multiple applications: vod2, vod3, vod4.

Now I would like to use allowedHTMLdomains.txt and allowedSWFdomains.txt to restrict which domains can play video.

I have changed the 2 files:

allowedHTMLdomains.txt contains only this:

```
purple.mydomain.com
```

allowedSWFdomains.txt contains only this:

```
purple.mydomain.com
```

Then restarted Adobe Flash Media Server.

Next I created a web page on a totally different server, banana.myotherdomain.org
and used this embedded code to place a video on the page:

```
<embed 
 height="377" width="640" 
 allowscriptaccess="always"
 allowfullscreen="true"  
 src="http://purple.mydomain.com/swfs/jwplayer.swf"
 flashvars="&streamer=rtmp:/vod2&file=testfile.flv" 
/>
</embed>
```

But it doesn't restrict anything.

I can still stream video from domains which are not specified in the allowed files.

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably restrict access to "http://purple.mydomain.com/swfs/jwplayer.swf" on your first server, refusing requests from other domains. My guess is that since the swf is actually hosted on purple, this is the domain that FMS checks.

Check out .htaccess on your server.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have been extremely frustrated with the lack of documentation about the allowedHTMLdomains.txt and allowedSWFdomains.txt files.

Your suggestion helped me find the answer.

allowedHTMLdomains.txt restricts which domains can view the video.

However, if you reference a Flash player located on the same server as the Flash Media Server, which is permitted in allowedSWFdomain.txt then you will be able to see view the video.

Comment: Glad to be of any help. Too bad that it's seems that since you didnt upvote my answer, the bounty went into the void...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the step by step:
1. Make sure you copy over all the files, including main.asc,  from the vod directory into your new directory.

2. Follow all of the instructions here closely to configure the secondary application : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_Deving/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773cfae-7ff3.html
3. Start out with allowedHMTLdomains and allowedSWFdomains having only a * this should be accessable to everyone
4. restart the FMS server using the `./server restart` command.  This is a test to make sure everyone should be able to view the video from any domain.
5. Next change only allowedHTMLdomains.txt to a domain which you would like to allow, remove the *
6. Restart the FMS server using the `./server restart` command
7. Now try to stream the video from a domain other than the one listed in allowedHTMLdomains.  It should not play